# How to add edit function to todolist application

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8

I am currently working on a todolist application.

What I want to do is to add an edit function to this app as shown in the image below.

First of all, I tried to pass only this.item.name from the child component (listItem.vue) to the parent component (addItemForm.vue) to be displayed in the input field when the edit icon is clicked, but it did not work.

If anyone can help me understand what I am trying to do, please let me know.

[image]

here is vue file.

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="todoListContainer">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2 id="title">TodoList</h2>
      <add-item-form v-on:reloadlist="getList()" />
    </div>
    <list-view :items="items" v-on:reloadlist="getList()" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import addItemForm from "./addItemForm.vue";
import listView from "./listView.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    addItemForm,
    listView,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getList() {
      axios
        .get("api/items")
        .then((response) => {
          this.items = response.data;
          console.log(this.items);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getList();
    console.log("create success!");
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.todoListContainer {
  width: 350px;
  margin: auto;
}

.heading {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 10px;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

addItemForm.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="addItem">
    <input type="text" v-model="item.name" />
    <font-awesome-icon
      icon="plus-square"
      @click="addItem()"
      :class="[item.name ? 'active' : 'inactive', 'plus']"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      item: {
        name: "",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      if (this.item.name == "") {
        return;
      }
      axios
        .post("api/item/store", {
          item: this.item,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status == 201) {
            this.item.name = "";
            this.$emit("reloadlist");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.addItem {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.plus {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.active {
  color: #00ce25;
}

.inactive {
  color: #999999;
}
</style>
```

listView.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <list-item
        :item="item"
        class="item"
        v-on:itemchanged="$emit('reloadlist')"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import listItem from "./listItem.vue";
export default {
  props: ["items"],
  components: {
    listItem,
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.item {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
</style>
```

listItem.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" @change="updateCheck()" v-model="item.completed" />
    <span :class="[item.completed ? 'completed' : '', 'itemText']">{{
      item.name
    }}</span>
    <button @click="removeItem()" class="trashcan">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="trash" />
    </button>
    <button @click="editItem" class="pencil">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="pencil" />
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ["item"],
  methods: {
    updateCheck() {
      axios
        .put("api/item/" + this.item.id, {
          item: this.item,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status == 200) {
            this.$emit("itemchanged");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    removeItem() {
      axios
        .delete("api/item/" + this.item.id)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status == 200) {
            this.$emit("itemchanged");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },

    editItem() {
      const text = this.item .name;
      this.$emit('custom-click', text);
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #999999;
}
.itemText {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.trashcan {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border: none;
  color: #ff0000;
  outline: none;
}
.pencil {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border: none;
  color: #1df548;
  outline: none;
}
</style>
```

items_table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateItemsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->boolean('completed')->default(false);
            $table->timestamp('completed_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('items');
    }
}
```

First of all, I tried to pass only this.item.name from the child component (listItem.vue) to the parent component (addItemForm.vue) to be displayed in the input field when the edit icon is clicked, but it did not work.

So I want the target text to appear in the input field when I first click on the edit symbol.

Postscript
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Postscript2
I debugged it by placing a breakpoint at the corresponding point in chrome's developer tools.
I confirmed that the value is passed up to @custom-click="$emit('custom-click', $event)" in listView.vue, but it does not seem to reach the edit function.
Also, I am getting a warning error as shown in the image.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

PostScript3
Vue.js devtools
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `can help me understand what I am trying to do` + `sharing 400 lines of code` is not a good match tbh. What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You emit 'custom-click' from listItem, that's good. Next is to listen to the event in the parent (listView) and re-emit to the *next* parent, app.vue.  Once app.vue has the item, you need to pass it back down as a prop to your AddItemForm.vue component and set it as the `<input>` v-model.

This is basically what you need to add to each component:

**listView.vue** (re-emit)

```html
<list-item
  :item="item"
  class="item"
  v-on:itemchanged="$emit('reloadlist')"
  @custom-click="$emit('custom-click', $event)"
/>
```

**App.vue** (listen to emit, find matching item in `this.items`, send it down as prop to addItemForm)

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h2 id="title">TodoList</h2>
  <add-item-form v-on:reloadlist="getList()" :editItem="editItem" />
</div>
<list-view :items="items" v-on:reloadlist="getList()" @custom-click="edit" />
```

```js
data: function () {
  editItem: null
},
methods: {
  edit(item) {
    this.editItem = this.items.find(i => i.name === item);
  }
}
```

**AddItemForm.vue** (set v-model using prop)

```js
props: {
  editItem: {
    type: Object,
    default() {
      return null;
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  editItem(newItem) {
    this.item = newItem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I have reflected what you described, but when I clicked on the edit symbol, the value did not appear in the input field.
I forgot to mention that I am using vue3, is it a writing method that does not work with vue3?
I have attached the changes I made in the postscript.

Comment: Since I can't run your code for you can you debug and maybe narrow down where the problem might be?  Use console log and/or dev tools and verify that 1) the first emit is working, 2) the second emit is working, 3) the correct item is being found in app.vue, 4) the prop is passed down to the addItemForm and set to the v-model.  Please figure out what step is failing.

Comment: I have added debugged info.
By the way, when I debug vuejs I usually do it using chrome developer tools, what is the most common way to debug vuejs?

Comment: @shozo by using the VueJS devtools.

Comment: @kissu
Thank you for your comment.
As I added, I still have the chrome extension Vue.js devtools, but this extension does not have debugging execution like the normal chrome developer tools, right?
I am not sure how to use this extension.

Comment: @shozo you do have in real-time, no need to "pause". But both can work well together.

Comment: @kissu 
I also learn how to use the tools.
It is good to know that everyone is using this tool.

Comment: @yoduh I had made a very silly mistake.
I wrote the edit function under the create function when I should have written it inside the method...
I confirmed that the clicked content is reflected in the input field successfully.
Next, I would like to add a process to make the plus mark an edit mark and apply the edited content.
If I have any questions, I will ask again.
Thank you very much.